# onMeasure(...) being passed MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, apparently wrongly

Tags: android, view, measurement

I've created a custom View that implements `onMeasure`:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    float width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);

    float height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

    float nominalHeight = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.nominalheight);
    float nominalWidth = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.nominalwidth);

    float aspectRatio = nominalWidth / nominalHeight;

    if( width / height > aspectRatio //too wide
            && (
                    widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST ||
                    widthMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED 
            )
            ) { 
        width -= (width - height * aspectRatio);
    }
    if( width / height < aspectRatio //too tall
            && (
                    heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST ||
                    heightMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED 
            )
            ) { 
        height -= (height - width / aspectRatio);
    }

    setMeasuredDimension((int)width, (int)height);
}
```

The intention is, where possible, to create a rectangle whose aspect ratio is the same as the one specified by `nominalheight` and `nominalwidth`.  Obviously if the function is passed `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY` then it should lay out with the dimension given in that direction.

I'm laying this `View` out with `WRAP_CONTENT` in the xml in both directions.  What's puzzling me is that, stepping through the onMeasure calls, half of them show MeasureSpec.AT_MOST and the routine calculates the correct rectangle, and the other half show MeasureSpec.EXACTLY and it obviously uses the given dimensions.  Even more puzzlingly, if I disable the conditionality (I would assume, from [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html) and the [example code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/LabelView.html), incorrectly) it works fine.

Why am I getting these alternating calls with different values, and how can I persuade Android to lay my View out in the correct dimensions?

Comment: What kind of ViewGroup are these views arranged in? (LinearLayout, FrameLayout, etc). I believe the parent view determines what the rules are for calling its childrens' onMeasure. You may have more luck with another kind of group. Also note that onMeasure can be called for multiple iterations as the dimensions get successfully locked down. I had a similar question myself a while back (fixed aspect ratio views) that I wrote up a fairly lengthy answer to, maybe that will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10522282/1236185

Comment: Thanks—in fact it was a `ViewGroup` problem.  I've created a reasonably complex `ViewGroup` and I'd lost track of where the laying out was occurring.  I'll write it all up properly tomorrow :)

Comment: I had the most success with putting my fixed aspect ratio view as the only child of a FrameLayout, as it was very lenient about child dimensions. If you're still looking for a solution that may help you.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks.  In fact I want to put a bunch of these in a grid (one reason for doing this is so I can display a load of 1:1.5 rectangles on a page of unknown size!) but I do also need to display one large one and I will almost certainly end up doing this :)

Comment: Tim—I've now solved my problem entirely and it turned out this was just a stupid mistake—I'm going to write it up later in a way that helps people look for the mistake I made.  My `onMeasure(...)` solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718450/telling-the-android-layout-inflater-how-large-wrap-content-should-be/10885032#10885032 :)